# Python how to trigger an API

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I have API on google functions that have two functions on it like:

- **add** (https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/iotUp?text=id)
- **delete** (https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/iotDown?text=id)

and each function works correctly (adds and deletes data on DB) when I load them in the web browser. The problem is, I can't do it in python script on Raspberry Pi 3. I want to use these URLs on open and close position of switch.

**Python script on RasPi**

```
#buttoninput
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import requests

myid="dedektor001"

def button_callback(channel):
    sys.stdout.write('\033c')
    print('open')
    requests.get("https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/iotUptext=myid,timeout=1")

def button_off(channel):
    sys.stdout.write('\033c')
    print('close');
    requests.get("https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/iotDowntext=myid,timeout=1")


GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD);


buttonon = 10
buttonoff = 8

GPIO.setup(buttonon, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN);
GPIO.setup(buttonoff, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN);

print("ok");

GPIO.add_event_detect(buttonon,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(buttonoff, GPIO.RISING, callback=button_off);

message= input("enter to exit")        

GPIO.cleanup();
```

This code works on the first toggle on switch but it freezes. prints "open" even if I change the swich position.

Comment: Except of the syntax error in the string there should also be some authentication, shouldn't it.

Comment: actually it works, just waits for reply i think. as i said, freezes after first toggle. @KlausD.

Comment: Have you tried to print some message without any requests? To check if the issue related to requests (doesn't look like) or to logic (maybe to event handlers which work only once)?

Comment: yes, it works properly without requests @extempl

Comment: Those urls in the `requests.get` calls don't look quite right, perhaps they should match the ones you provide at the top of your question? (Either way they don't look like valid URLs because of the path/querystring mix up at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Echoing what @Henry Woody said, your urls don't look like they are properly formatted.  Here is what you should do using `requests`:

```
requests.get("https://xxx.cloudfunctions.net/iotUp", params={
    'text': myid,
    'timeout': 1,
})
```

You can do something similar for your `iotDown` function.